# Person who doesn't share

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the equivalent word for a person who doesn't want to communicate to share any of his/her *secrets*, *life's stories* or *personal information*?

Need some words related to the above described description...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This person would be called **private**.

"Private" is used to describe not only information, but also people who don't share personal information freely.

There are a variety of expressions to describe someone who does not wish to disclose other types of information, such as "secretive," "tight-lipped," and "discreet."  However, "private" seems the best for the situation you've described.

Two other possible candidates are **unforthcoming** and **guarded**.

From Oxford Dictionaries online:

*private*

1.3 (Of a person) choosing not to reveal their thoughts and feelings to others: he was a very private man

*unforthcoming*

1 (Of a person) not willing to divulge information: the sergeant seemed unforthcoming, so he enquired at the gate

*guarded*

Cautious and having possible reservations: he has given a guarded welcome to the idea

Comment: Thank you for your answer... How about **reticent**? What does it meant and will it suit my description?

Comment: Yes, "reticent" is a good word as well. We could certainly add that to the list, although I feel it's used a bit more generally to describe a person who is typically quiet.

Comment: Oh my..! I think I've made my actual question wrong. I want to know person who doesn't want to communicate his feelings and thoughts... Can you say some other words with this meaning? Please.

Comment: Please don't remove/erase the current answer... It's a vocabulary of words I've been looking for a long time...

Comment: I think "private" still applies, as per the definition. It doesn't show a general disinclination to speaking or conversing, as some of the adjectives indicating shyness do, but rather a disinclination to share personal feelings and information.

Answer (score 2):

We often call such a person a *very private person*.

One very private person was [Josephine Tey](http://www.josephinetey.net/).

Comment: I'm looking for a single word...

Answer (score 2):

That person might be closed or guarded.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved if you could explain *why* those terms are appropriate, for example, by excerpting dictionary definitions. I encourage you to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on submitting good answers.

Answer (score 2):

We might call this person [reserved](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reserved):

> formal or self-restrained in manner and relationship; avoiding familiarity or intimacy with others:
>   *a quiet, reserved man.*

Answer (score 1):

An  adjective is  [secretive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/secretive) ( person):

> - Having or marked by an inclination to secrecy; not open, forthright, or frank.

also , according to context, an  [introvert](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/introvert) :

> - a shy person; a person concerned primarily with inner thoughts and feelings rather than with the physical or social environment.

Comment: I'd never use *introvert* for this. That's sure only to offend introverts.

Comment: @curiousdannii No, it doesn't, believe me.

Comment: @AndrewLeach well it might not offend everyone, but I do get really annoyed when people misunderstand what introversion is. It has absolutely nothing to do with shyness, and shyness has absolutely nothing to do with being guarded!