# What is it called when someone doesn't want to share stuff/feelings to others, even close ones, in fear of being judged?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is there a phrase, word, or a term for this condition? And I'm not specifically talking about fear of intimacy, I'm asking for something more general. Such as not sharing stuff with friends, family, in fear of being judged.

Comment: Showing your research efforts is important.  Have you googled 'fear of being judged', 'not sharing' etc...?

Comment: [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208741/person-who-doesnt-share](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208741/person-who-doesnt-share)
This could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'd say such a person is **"emotionally insecure"**.  (see No 1 below)

> - [**From Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_security)  "Emotional insecurity or simply insecurity is a feeling of general unease or nervousness that may be triggered by perceiving of oneself to be vulnerable or inferior in some way, or a sense of vulnerability or instability which threatens one's self-image or ego."
> - [**From Science Simplified**](https://sparkonit.com/2013/03/21/emotional-insecurity-cause-aftermath-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it/) - "Emotional insecurity or simply insecurity is a feeling of unease or nervousness that is triggered by perceiving oneself to be worthless, unloved or not good enough that they don’t measure up especially when compared to someone else."
> - [**From Exploring Your Mind**](https://exploringyourmind.com/when-the-lack-of-confidence-invades-emotional-insecurity/) - "To better understand the world of emotional insecurity and how it affects us, it’s important to know what it means to be an insecure person. Here are some of the most common characteristics of emotionally insecure people. They are the following:
>
>   1. **Fear of criticism, judgments, and assessments from others.**
>   2. Constant
>        need to show their achievements and receive praise in order to feel
>        valid and capable.
>   3. Tendency to be perfectionistic and competitive.
>        They’re usually defensive. Have low self-esteem.
>   4. They attempt to
>        spread doubt and insecurity to others. Frequently use false modesty.
>   5. They greatly distrust themselves."